# Hide my system information from web pages

Tags: networking

How to stop web pages to gather my system information (Linux i686, 2 Cores, notebook`s model 504U etc). I use Firefox. I know how to restrict the browser to access files I choose. Know that file /proc/cpuinfo has some info but not all info it has I want to be stopped gathered.

Comment: You may look at a sandbox like [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) or something mentioned in this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/best-method-to-sandbox-x-applications-in-ubuntu this may be a starting point I am not sure.

Comment: Could you please add link to the page which shows all information about the system (such as number of cores, laptop model, etc.)? I suspect that Flash Player may know this info, but not sure about browser itself. For example my favorite site for such purpose - http://browserspy.dk/ does not show number of cores, CPU model and laptop model (tested with Chromium, Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: In google account ( login&security) earlier it was showing 504U. Or someone there. Now I can not find section. +http://browserspy.dk/os.php ... They know how = everybody know how. @N0rbert

Comment: I know. @student

Comment: browserspy.dk does not but others can. I can not find the link in my browsing history. But it was written with dark on white (2 Cores). @N0rbert

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox/Privacy

Comment: And check with https://whatleaks.com/ .

Comment: No, can not find. But https://clickclickclick.click can do a lot. @N0rbert

Comment: I want Firefox or os to send " " (nothing, empty). @Panther

Comment: UPD: some information about my pc I have found at /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/ folder, even the same one x504u in  /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/bios_version, and without root privilege. Perhaps web pages using javascript (how to be in the today`s modern world without javascript) get this and others similar files

Answer (score 1):

One common "fingerprinting" method used by web sites to identify users involves querying your browser concerning what fonts are available.  If you've installed any fonts that aren't in the base packages of your OS, the exact list greatly narrows the number of other characteristics a site can gather to say "This is the John Smith who lives at 1234 Home Lane in Anytown, USA."  There are other queries that can be added to this, as well.

The obvious-seeming way to defeat this kind of "system fingerprinting" is to do your browsing with a 100% box-stock, unmodified install running in a VM.  That way, all the sites will get is "This user is using Ubuntu 18.04 in English, on Eastern Standard Time and in US dollars, without any user modifications."  Not, perhaps, as generic as "straight from the USB stick" Windows 10.1, but by this point even a dynamic IP address gives away more than the system fingerprint.

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox/Privacy

Comment: @Panther Sounds like an alternative answer, to me.

Comment: Whole books / wiki pages can be written on the topic. Ironically the more you hide this I formation the more you stand out, the number of browsers that send out nothing, as the OP envisions, is 3 to 4 orders of magnitude lower than firefox or whatever. You can test that.